# Neither percentile_cont nor percentile_disc are calculating the desired 75th percentile in PostgreSQL 9.6.3

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Working with the percentile functions, but I am not getting the desired output. I would say "incorrect", but the functions are probably working as they are intended, and I am just not understanding them properly.

These are the numbers I am working with:

```
n = 32

160000
202800
240000
250000
265000
280000
285000
300000
300000
300000
300000
300000
309000
325000
350000
358625
364999.92
393750
400000
420000
425000
450000
450000
463500
475000
475000
505808
525000
550000
567300
665000
900000
```

My understanding of `percentile_cont` is that it will aggregate two numbers if the count is even in that it will add them and then divide by two. My understanding of `percentile_disc` is that it will just select the lowest number if the count is even.

This is my understanding of calculating a percentile using the 50th (median) as an example:

If the number of numbers (n) is odd, pick the number in the middle; if the number is even, you average the two numbers in the middle. So in this case, there are 32 numbers, so the median = `(358625 + 364999.92) / 2 = 361812.46`. `percentile_cont` returns the correct value since it averages the two values; `percentile_disc` returns the incorrect value since it picks the lowest of the two.

Regarding other percentiles, the 10th for example, my understanding is you multiple the percentile by the number of numbers (n) to get the index: `.10 * 32 = 3.2 index` in this case. You are then supposed to round up to the nearest whole number and that is your percentile value. If the index is a whole number, then you average the number in the index with the number right after it.

In that case, `percentile_cont` is wrong because it returns `251500` which isn't even a number I can arrive at. The closest I can get is averaging `24000, 250000, 265000` which is `251666.67`. `percentile_disc` returns the correct result of `250000`.

**But the real kicker is this one**: the 75th. It should return `469250` according to my calculations. `index = (32*.75) = 24`, and that index should result in `(463500 + 475000) = 469250`. `percentile_disc` returns `463500`; `percentile_cont` returns `466375`, which again I can't arrive at that number for the life of me.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    itemcode, 
    COUNT(itemcode) AS n, 
    PERCENTILE_DIST(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS 10th,
    PERCENTILE_DIST(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS 25th,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS median,
    AVG(price) AS mean,
    PERCENTILE_DIST(0.65) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS 65th,
    PERCENTILE_DIST(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS 75th,
    PERCENTILE_DIST(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) AS 90th
FROM items
WHERE itemcode = 26 AND removed IS NULL
GROUP BY itemcode;
```

Note: there are no cases where `removed` is not `NULL`.

What do I need to do to get this working correctly and with consistency? Do I need to write a function that checks `n` first before to decide which `percentile_disc` or `percentile_cont` based on whether it is even or odd?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa09c/9

Comment: can you please reduce the post to one function, one question with sample data, output and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted this question to Reddit and was able to get some help.

Apparently, the `percentile_cont` function, in addition to `percentile` and `percentile.inc` functions in Excel, calculate using the C=1 variant of linear interpolation as explained in this Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Second_variant.2C_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000043-QINU.60.22.27.7F

Apparently, what I have been using is called Empirical Distribution with Averaging.

So the native functions of PostgreSQL won't work so well and will need to make a custom function which I will post when I am done. (I suspect it will use the old `ntile` method from before 9.4, but still looking into it).

But anyway, that is why it is off.